# Find marketAuthority/SerumVaultSigner (owner of non-ATA vault accounts)

Tags: serum-market

When fetching pools from the Raydium Liquidity API one of the keys listed is marketAuthority. It appears in the Raydium Swap txs as SerumVaultSigner, so I would like to retrieve this value to make swaps, ideally without accessing the API. I noticed that many of the keys given by the API can also be found by looking at the Serum Market Initialization tx, but I cannot find the marketAuthority field. I did find that the marketAuthority usually seems to be the owner of the marketBaseVault and marketQuoteVault accounts, but I don't know if this is neccessarily always true.

1. Is there a way to get the marketAuthority from the Serum Market Initialization tx alone?
2. Is the marketAuthority always the owner of the marketBaseVault and marketQuoteVault accounts? If so, can I derive their owners without RPC calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Market.getAssociatedAuthority` method from the Raydium SDK. From the code, it seems this value can be derived from the program and market public keys.